# 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, std

i compile the project with the mingw and the project is cool compiler .
this is a part of my code

```
#include "astnodecodegenerator.hpp"
#include "utility.hpp"
#include "constants.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
```

.
.
.
.

```
void AstNodeCodeGenerator::visit(StringConst& str) 
{ 
    emit_la("a0", (std::string("str_const") + std::to_string(stringtable().get_idx(str.token.get_val()))).c_str());
}

void AstNodeCodeGenerator::visit(IntConst& int_const) 
{
    emit_la("a0", (std::string("int_const") + std::to_string(inttable().get_idx(int_const.token.get_val()))).c_str());
}
```

the error is:

```
error :'to_string' is not a member of 'std' emit_la<"a0",<std::string(("str_const") + std::to_string(stringtable().get_idx(str.token.get_val()))).c_str());
```

Comment: `to_string` is a C++11 feature. You may have to turn that on.

Comment: Use `-std=c++11` on the command line to turn on C++11.

Comment: this is part of makefile:----CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -Wno-write-strings ../../include/boost

Comment: what your mean's turn on ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported on MinGW because of limitations in the MinGW runtime that need changes from MinGW developers.

Take a look at these:

- [Bug 52015 - std::to_string does not work under MinGW](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52015)
- [Bug 59076 - std::to_string(int ) could not be found in GCC 4.8.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59076)

If you can use Boost, a good alternative is [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) (been there, done that).

Comment: have the mingw devs made any progress... there last bugpost about this 1571 was "closed" due to "out of date" but this is december 2014 and I STILL GET THIS PROBLEM!@!!! ARGH pulling hair here!!!!

Comment: @BrianJack Its 2017, still gettin :D